# Get text between two ""

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am struggling with the following text:

```
c(\Study:\", \"Job:\", \"Branch:\", \"Position:\", \"Naming:\", NA, NA, \"Banker\", \"VP of Sales\", \"\", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)"
```

I would like to get from a regex, the `VP of Sales`. Instead of the `VP of Sales` other things can be exactly at this place.

I tried the following, `\\\"(.*?)\"` which captures all the text around, but not the `VP of Sales`.

Any suggestions? I appreciate your reply!

Comment: Is what you want always in the nth column? Is it the only column that contains spaces or contains "of?" What do other rows of data look like? Be more specific. Otherwise, I'll simply recommend `\\\"(VP of Sales)\"`

Comment: Your input is incorrect. You have missed one `"` between `Study` in the beginning of the text.
Correct regex should be `\\\"(.*?)\\\"`

Comment: @WesFoster Instead of the `VP of Sales` other things can be exactly at this place. I want the 7th column basically. Any suggestions?

Comment: @UladzimirPalekh No there is no `"` missing. That`s exactly my problem. The data looks like this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the data you want will always be in the same column, just do this:

```
/(?:, [^,]+){7}, \\\"(.*?)\\\".*/g
```

Basically, this skips the first **7** columns (delimited by `, [^,]`) (number can be changed in `{7}`) and captures the data in quotes that comes immediately after it, then ignores the rest.

Here's a demo: http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=96828

Comment: Note that this will fail if a previous field contains a comma (e.g. "Technical, senior"), which seems plausible. I doubt there's much better to do with regex though.

Comment: Correct. Good to note, @Aaron